# Show "Today Date" in the "Title Attribute" of a tooltip – Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, date, attributes

I am calling the date of today with JS

```
  <script>
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var n = new Date();
    var y = n.getFullYear();
    var m = n.getMonth();
    var d = n.getDate();
    document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
  </script>
```

Now I am trying to use this string in tooltip as a title attribute (bootstrap).

```
<span class="font-size-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="here should go the string TODAY">Today</span>
```

It just doesn't work. Anyone out there who sees the issue? How can I add the id="today" in a title or basically to show up in the tooltip?

PS. If I nest it in P the date shows up fine (so JS is fine):

```
<p id="today"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `title` as a function. I also shortened your date calculation using `toLocaleString()`:

```js
$('span.custom').tooltip({
  title: function() {
    return new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", {day: '2-digit', month: 'long', year: 'numeric'})
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="custom font-size-1 font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true">Today</span>
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you Anurag! This does work. However, now everything which is wrapped in <span> gets the tooltip. Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: @SunDevil Just add a class to the span where you need the tooltip and use it..updated the answer to use a `custom` class

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show the date on the tooltip of the span, right? Just set the title to `today` and give the span an `id`. Does this work for you?

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var n = new Date();
    var y = n.getFullYear();
    var m = n.getMonth();
    var d = n.getDate();
    document.getElementById("today").title = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
```

```html
<span class="font-size-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" id="today">Today</span>
```

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I accepted also your answer and yes it worked. Now your answer is gone. I am very new to this. I'll try to be more specific in the future.